# How to use the von Neumann neighborhood to setup indices in 3D space?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

Given an index (x,y) in two dimensional space (grid)
I can derive the neighbor indices through the von Neumann neighborhood:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_neighborhood.

How would I best expand this concept to three dimensional space (with minimal runtime complexity) 
to derive the neighbor indices of (x,y,z) using the von Neumann neighborhood?

Can someone help me out with some pseudo / C code to illustrate it?

Comment: Are you trying to build the neighborhood of an arbitrary range r? what do you mean by the neighbor indices? is it the manhattan distance? what is an index (x,y)? did you mean a coordinate system?

Comment: Yes to question one and three. (x,y) for the index anlong the x- and y-axis.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about the 6 immediate neighbours, the most efficient way will be to hardcode it:

```
int neighbour_offsets[3][6] = {
  {1, 0, 0},
  {0, 1, 0},
  {0, 0, 1},
  {-1, 0, 0},
  {0, -1, 0},
  {0, 0, -1},
};
```

For the neighbours of rank <= `r`, for fixed dimension nested `for` loops will work:

```
for (x = -r; x <= r; ++x) {
    r_x = r - abs(x);
    for (y = -r_x; y <= r_x; ++y) {
        r_y = r_x - abs(y);
        for (z = -r_y; z <= r_y; ++z) {
            printf("%d, %d, %d\n", x, y, z);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want the neighbours at distance `d == r` rather than `d <= r`, use `z := {-r_y, r_y}`.

For arbitrary low dimension, recursion will work (and be reasonably clear); for high dimension you'd do best to start with a recursive solution and convert it to a loop.  In high dimensions (D >> r) the offset will be zero in most dimensions most of the time anyway.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am searching for a solution that takes the distance into account.
So your example would fit distance == 1. Any suggestions about that?

Answer (score 0):

This seems a bit simple, so I may have misunderstood your question, but for arbitrary `r` in three dimensions, in C, looping through the neighbouring cells and processing them or storing the indices would be something like:

```
for ( i = -r ; i <= r ; i++ )
    for ( j = -r ; j <= r ; j++ )
        for ( k = -r ; k <= r ; k++ )
            if ( abs(i) + abs(j) + abs(k) <= r ) {
                do whatever in the cell (x+i,y+j,z+k).
                }
```

Note that this is not the most efficient way, but probably the most straight-forward.

Comment: I think this would give me the "Moore neighborhood": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_neighborhood, which would be a cube in 3D. The "v. Neumann neighborhood" would rather have a "diamond" shape.

Comment: A good visual example would be:
http://www.google.de/imgres?imgurl=http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/vonNeumannNeighborhood_800.gif&imgrefurl=http://mathworld.wolfram.com/vonNeumannNeighborhood.html&h=303&w=303&sz=6&tbnid=Y211iZ6XqiAjUM:&tbnh=72&tbnw=72&prev=/search%3Fq%3Dvon%2Bneumann%2Bneighborhood%26tbm%3Disch%26tbo%3Du&zoom=1&q=von+neumann+neighborhood&usg=__zuAG1IDIRKOrbbjnFrQJRiZLV8U=&docid=wqFpUxPo34xmlM&hl=de&sa=X&ei=g9fpT5O4EMbHtAbF3q2-Dg&ved=0CGEQ9QEwAw&dur=0

Comment: @diver_182: Nope, the `if`-statement at the end of the loops makes it a Neumann neighbourhood.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the index of a particular point then the answer is easy:

let D be the manhattan distance of 2 points in the 3D space:

```
  D = abs(x1-x2) + abs (y1-y2) + abs (z1 - z2)
```

and that would be your index.

If you are trying to build the 3D Octahedron of the von Neumann neighborhood then the easiest way is to use recursion.

In fact, it is easy to prove that if a point **X** is in the **R** range of **Y** and **Y** is in the **K** range of **Z** then **X** is at least in the **K+R** range of **Z** (Go from X to Y in R steps then from Y to Z in K other steps).

This solution requiere O(n) time where n is the exact number of point in the neighboorhood.
It can be easily optimized to avoid redunduncy.

An example of algorithm that use a similar technic is the Dijkstra algorithm. 
Altough it's main purpose is path finding, its principle is to explore all neighboors of range 1, then 2 and so on (On unweighted graphs).

Comment: Thanks for your support (especially the explanation on the runtime complexity, was helpfull).